# How to use height() on a div with an image inside that's using width: 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, width

so I have

```
div {
    width: 20%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
<div>
<img />
</div>
```

So the image scales appropriately, depending on the width of the div. I want to find the height of the image using jQuery.

```
var imgHeight = $(img).height();
console.log(imgHeight);
```

However, it's coming back as 0 (the height of the div). How do I get the rendered height of the image?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to check it after the image has finished downloading. Can you  show a bit more of the code where you are checking height so we can make suggestions on making it asynchronous?

Comment: you guys are right, I did have it in my document ready. i suck! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As loganfsmyth has commented, the you need to wait for the image to finish loading.

Are you putting the code in document.ready ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var imgHeight = $(img).height();
  console.log(imgHeight);
});
```